# When training the Siamese network, the model accuracy does not change

Tags: python, keras, siamese-network

I want to use the twin RNN network for time series classification, using contrastive loss as the loss function, but no matter how to adjust the margin parameter, the accuracy of the model is always 50%

Below is the structure of the network:
I directly changed the keras.io website case

```py
def euclidean_distance(vects):
  
    x, y = vects
    sum_square = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.square(x - y), axis=1, keepdims=True)
    return tf.math.sqrt(tf.math.maximum(sum_square, tf.keras.backend.epsilon()))

input = layers.Input((1000, 4))

x = SimpleRNN(100, input_shape=(1000,4))(input)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)
embedding_network = keras.Model(input, x)

input_1 = layers.Input((1000, 4))
input_2 = layers.Input((1000, 4))

tower_1 = embedding_network(input_1)
tower_2 = embedding_network(input_2)

merge_layer = layers.Lambda(euclidean_distance)([tower_1, tower_2])
normal_layer = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(merge_layer)
output_layer = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(normal_layer)
siamese = keras.Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=output_layer)
```

[image]

Comment: Provide more details about the training dataset, likely to be the cause of the problem

Comment: The training set is a multi-feature time series with shape (1000,4), labels 0 and 1, the total sample size is 10000, and a time series binary classification needs to be done

Comment: So you didn’t reshape the dataset as a 3D tensor? I mean, where are time steps here?

Comment: The time step is 1000 and the final input to the model is (10452, 1000, 4), where 10452 is the number of samples

Comment: What is the loss function here?